# System.OperationCanceledException Thrown On Every Event From Azure Event Hubs In Xamarin

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to send an event from my web API every time a user sends their information to another user, then listen for the event within Xamarin and query the database for updates every time an event comes in. My issue is that it seems that I'm getting this error every time an event comes in on my Xamarin project.

The [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-messaging-exceptions) doesn't seem to be very helpful in my case as it only says

> An attempt is made to invoke an operation on an object that has
>   already been closed, aborted, or disposed. In rare cases, the ambient
>   transaction is already disposed.

Here is my code that initializes the event hubs client in my Xamarin project.

```
 public async void InitClient()
    {
        string consumerGroup = EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName;
        BlobContainerClient storageClient = new BlobContainerClient(StorageConnectionString, StorageContainerName);
        eventProcessor = new EventProcessorClient(storageClient, consumerGroup, EventHubConnectionString, EventHubName);
        eventProcessor.ProcessEventAsync += EventProcessor_ProcessEventAsync; ;
        eventProcessor.ProcessErrorAsync += EventProcessor_ProcessErrorAsync;
        await eventProcessor.StartProcessingAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Processing started");
    }
```

And every message ends up in the process error function with a stack trace of

```
    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.ExceptionDispatcher.Throw (System.Exception exception) [0x00006] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult] (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x000f5] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.RequestResponseAmqpLink+RequestAsyncResult.End (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.RequestResponseAmqpLink.EndRequest (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpCbsLink+SendTokenAsyncResult+<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<GetAsyncSteps>b__3 (Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpCbsLink+SendTokenAsyncResult thisPtr, System.IAsyncResult r) [0x0000c] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.IteratorAsyncResult`1[TIteratorAsyncResult].EnumerateSteps (Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.IteratorAsyncResult`1+CurrentThreadType[TIteratorAsyncResult] state) [0x00158] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.ExceptionDispatcher.Throw (System.Exception exception) [0x00006] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult] (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x000f5] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult`1[TAsyncResult].End (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpCbsLink.EndSendToken (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpCbsLink+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<SendTokenAsync>b__1 (System.IAsyncResult a) [0x00000] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`2[System.IAsyncResult,System.DateTime].invoke_TResult_T(System.IAsyncResult)
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-10/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:534 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.CreateReceivingLinkAsync (Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpConnection connection, System.Uri endpoint, Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer.EventPosition eventPosition, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.UInt32 prefetchCount, System.Nullable`1[T] ownerLevel, System.Boolean trackLastEnqueuedEventProperties, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00431] in <2347303e556c4d659b494dac79430634>:0 
  at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.OpenConsumerLinkAsync (System.String consumerGroup, System.String partitionId, Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer.EventPosition eventPosition, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.UInt32 prefetchCount, System.Nullable`1[T] ownerLevel, System.Boolean trackLastEnqueuedEventProperties, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001a3] in <2347303e556c4d659b494dac79430634>:0 
  at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConsumer.CreateConsumerLinkAsync (System.String consumerGroup, System.String partitionId, Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer.EventPosition eventStartingPosition, System.UInt32 prefetchCount, System.Nullable`1[T] ownerLevel, System.Boolean trackLastEnqueuedEventProperties, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000af] in <2347303e556c4d659b494dac79430634>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1[T].OnCreateAsync (System.TimeSpan timeout) [0x00077] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1[TValue].GetOrCreateAsync (System.TimeSpan timeout) [0x00154] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1[TValue].GetOrCreateAsync (System.TimeSpan timeout) [0x001fc] in <9cea9f83a18d449284cb86dea42f9d95>:0 
  at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConsumer.ReceiveAsync (System.Int32 maximumMessageCount, System.Nullable`1[T] maximumWaitTime, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0019e] in <2347303e556c4d659b494dac79430634>:0 
  at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConsumer.ReceiveAsync (System.Int32 maximumMessageCount, System.Nullable`1[T] maximumWaitTime, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00591] in <2347303e556c4d659b494dac79430634>:0 
  at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Primitives.EventProcessor`1+<>c__DisplayClass61_0[TPartition].<CreatePartitionProcessor>g__performProcessing|1 () [0x0020c] in <2347303e556c4d659b494dac79430634>:0 
  at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Primitives.EventProcessor`1+<>c__DisplayClass61_0[TPartition].<CreatePartitionProcessor>g__performProcessing|1 () [0x0044f] in <2347303e556c4d659b494dac79430634>:0
```

[image: Event hubs error]

I'm just having an issue diagnosing what could be the cause and what could cause the event object to be closed, or if i'm not doing something correctly, which I find incredibly confusing because my code is reflected directly from the Microsoft Docs tutorial. Any pointers in the right direction or leads to what could be wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I've found that when I create a console application to receive events, it works flawlessly. The issue occurs when in Xamarin. I'm not quite sure what could be causing it on Xamarin's side. I am initiating the client after the user logs in and at the appearance of the home page.

Comment: According to the error, the `eventProcessor` variable seems to get disposed before it is supposed to. Can you share more code of that class, so I could see the rest of the lifecycle of that variable? Also, place an Exception Catchpoint" and see exactly where/which line the exception is caught.

Comment: @Saamer Thanks for the reply. The full class code is here https://pastebin.com/Ns6FmbQz as a sidenote, I'm using a IoC container, so maybe this could cause the issue? Also, I am unable to add a try catch because the error is not within the code, it's an error retrieved from event hubs and just goes straight to the error event handler function.

Comment: This looks to be an issue of some sort within the network stack.  The exception is being triggered because the operation for sending the authorization token to the Event Hubs service is timing out.  Since the authorization is shared for all links on the connection, this is likely the first time the connection has been initialized.   You may want to try using WebSockets to see if it is a port issue.  This sample illustrates doing so: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor/samples/Sample02_ProcessorWithCustomOptions.cs#L64

Comment: @JesseSquire I added the processor options and everything works great now. Thank you so much! If you could write your comment as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: Glad that it helped.  Posted as an answer as well, for better discoverability should others run into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be an issue of some sort within the network stack. The exception is being triggered because the operation for sending the authorization token to the Event Hubs service is timing out. Since the authorization is shared for all links on the connection, this is likely the first time the connection has been initialized. You may want to try using WebSockets to see if it is a port issue. [This sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor/samples/Sample02_ProcessorWithCustomOptions.cs#L64) illustrates doing so.